# Bootstrap 4 выравнивание по вертикали блоков

Tags: css, bootstrap

Посмотрел некоторые ответы по этому вопросу здесь, но на свой вопрос не могу найти.
Суть в следующем: надо выравнять блоки внутри другого по вертикали, но примеры с оф. сайта почему-то не работает. На фото как выводиться логика и внизу как желательно
Как можно исправить или вариант только через JS провести?

```
<div class="row  align-items-center parent-row">
    <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="row justify-content-start">
            <a href="/"><img src="<?= $logo ?>" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <img src="/protected/m/img/logo_copyright.png" alt="Copyright">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 ">
        <div class="row justify-content-end align-items-center">
            <a href="mailto:...">
                <img src="/protected/m/img/logo_email.png" alt="email"></a>
            <a href="skype:...?add">
                <img src="/protected/m/img/logo_skype.png" alt="Skype"></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/...">
                <img src="/protected/m/img/logo_githab.png"
                     alt="GitHab"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header, footer {
    margin: 5px 0;
    padding: 5px 0;

    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.parent-row {
    height: inherit;
    margin: -5px 0;
    padding: -5px 0;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как желательно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQqOk.png Не совсем понятно что надо сделать, можно конкретней показать на примере (нарисовать) ? P.S. У меня всё хорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё оказывается работает. Загвоздка оказалась в том, что строка row  имеет высоту максимального объекта, входящего в неё. Добавил дополнительный стиль с высотой, равной родительской и всё заработало. Код поменяю на итоговый, вдруг кому пригодиться.  Вопрос считаю решенным. ***Благодарю всех откликнувшихся***.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить в row

*align-items-center*

---

или же если для отдельного блока к примеру col-4 то к нему добавляется

*align-self-center*

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/ - документация Bootstrap, пригодится на будущее.

Comment: align-items-center стоит в примере, не работает, а также align-self-center тоже. Все, что делаю по bootstrap, делаю по официальной документации. Появилась мысль - может это связано с тем что я применяю это к div, который просто лежит в родительском, а надо передать внутреннему div размер родителя? Буду пробовать, но ответа тоже буду ждать. Спасибо

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку на текущий процесс?

Comment: Работа пока на локальной машине, код футера полностью выложен, если что надо добавлю

Comment: а вы пробовали добавить это в row внутри col-4 ?

Comment: да, итог тот же. Спасибо! Уже завтра с утра перетресу все на свежую голову